# Enable GitHub Dependabot Updates for actions used in Composite actions

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot

I have a GitHub repository which hosts GitHub Actions logic shared among other GitHub repositories.
The file structure is:

```
.github
|_ .workflows
  |_ shared-workflow-1
     |_ ...
  |_ shared-workflow-2
     |_ ...
|_ custom-action-1
     |_ action.yaml
|_ custom-action-2
     |_ action.yaml
```

(Note that the workflows HAD to be declared in .github/workflows because of GitHub constraints, but the custom actions can be declared at repository root level, and can thus simply be called with `my-github-logic-repo@custom-action1@main`.)

My `custom-action-*` actions are [composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action), which rely themselves on GitHub actions from the marketplace, which I would like to be automatically updated by Dependabot.

I have enabled Dependabot on the repository with the following `.github/dependabot.yml`:

```
version: 2

updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
```

But the issue is that Dependabot only open Pull Requests to update actions inside the workflows, and it completely ignores the actions inside my own custom composite actions.

Is there a way to make Dependabot look at my custom actions when checking for updates, or is it plain not supported at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Dependabot issue](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/4178), composite actions are supported, but you need to point dependabot to each subdirectory in the configuration:

```yaml
  - package-ecosystem: github-actions
    directory: /  # Still required to update workflows
    schedule:
      interval: weekly

  - package-ecosystem: github-actions
    directory: /custom-action-1
    schedule:
      interval: weekly

  - package-ecosystem: github-actions
    directory: /custom-action-2
    schedule:
      interval: weekly
```

Comment: This is cumbersome but it works well, thank you. I'll be watching for https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/5137 to be implemented for future simplification of the Dependabot.yaml file.

Comment: @cmousset Yeah, looks like wildcards are maybe coming at some point, which would be nice. As an aside, maintaining a repository with multiple actions and reusable workflows myself, I've come around to thinking it's preferable to have each action in a separate repository: simplifies versioning and releasing a lot, and doesn't have this problem here either.